# How do I change a Tkinter theme globally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, themes, ttk

I am programming a Tkinter program that shows details off of a website without downloading the website (i add the info manually).

But in my opinion, Tkinter on Linux looks like Windows 95, so I decided to change to `clam` theme so the buttons and other stuff looks nicer.

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam')
```

It works in the main window and `tkinter.messagebox` windows, but in `Toplevel()` windows, the theme isn't applied.

Does anyone know how to globally change the theme (including in `Toplevel()` windows)? Thanks :)

Comment: For me `s.theme_use()` is applied globally, including the ttk widgets inside Toplevel windows. Are you sure you don't have some non ttk widgets in the toplevels? You write main windows (plural) is it a typo or do you have several Tk instances?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo.

Comment: Ohh I didn't know that you had to use the ttk widgets all the time because I didn't realize I was using ttk widgets in the main window. Thank you for the answer @j_4321

Comment: @j_4321 but what if i wanted to use `ttkthemes` with `s.theme_use()` is there a way?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, `s = ttkthemes.ThemedStyle()`

Comment: @j_4321 but that creats a completely new instance of Tk() and then in my other gui i have a images, and it creats errors, anyway to use with toplevels?

Comment: @CoolCloud For me it does not create a new Tk window. I don't have enough details to help, you should ask a new question.

Comment: @j_4321 Its fine, thanks for the idea, ive found a way around

Comment: @CoolCloud could you explain your way around? it would help other people with the same problem :D

Comment: Also @CoolCloud the likely reason it was opening a new instance of tkinter is because you were using the python interpreter...it likes to get in your way ;D

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 my case was diff i was working with classes and imported custom entry class on to on my main project so i wanted it to blend in with theme of main project so i made an instance in  the class module to have the theme and there was the issue, well, i just made the widget `ttk` and the desired theme got applied to it automatically without creating a new `Tk()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a TTK theme requires using TTK's widgets, not Tkinter's. Thank you @j_4321 for pointing this out!